# What to do when you can't find how your device was registered?

Tags: linux, usb, network-adapter, kernel

Before Linux Kernel 3.0 (2.6.39) I can run the following command:

```
# ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Now I can't. I got an error saying that this device was not found.
I've tried to unplug my usb dongle, plug and check how it is registered but i don't get any useful output.

What should I do when dmesg dont help? How could I identify how my device was registered?

Thank you.

Comment: I can find my device through lsusb. My device is: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:1002 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v2 [Atheros AR9001U-(2)NG] It used to work with ar9170usb but now, with 3.0, it was replaced by carl9170. When I plug my wireless usb dongle, carl9170 appears in lsmod but dmesg doesn't show how it's identified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your new kernel has the required modules built for the device in question (helps to know the chipset - atheros, prismI/II, marvell, etc..)

1. `cd` into your Linux source directory
2. Execute: `make menuconfig`
3. Traverse the network devices section and look for your device's module (and enable).  You can get help on each selection from the ncurses interface you see, and *usually* you see the name of the module that the functionality is provided as.
4. `make modules modules_install ; depmod -a`
5. `modprobe modname` <- get this information from step 3.

Apologies if you've already tried the above - not sure how things have changed in 3.x, but it sounds like you've simply not built in the support for your device.